# Intersection of family of non negative integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $F=\{(-x,x) : x~\text{is a non negative integer} \}$, then what is $\bigcap F$ ?

My approach shows that this should be (0,0) = 0, but is this the null set in this context, because the answer is the interval containing zero, im not sure if those two are the same thing?

Comment: "Interval" $(0,0)$ does not contain $0$. There are no real numbers $x$ that satisfy $x>0$ and $x<0$ as well. You could say that $(0,0)=\varnothing$.

Comment: @dhrab would that same argument hold for the [0,0]?

Comment: There is a real number $x$ that satisfies $x\geq0$ and $x\leq0$. Number $x=0$ does and it is unique in doing so. So here we come to $[0,0]=\{0\}$.

Comment: @dhrab So I'm confused about the difference between {0} and the empty set, are they the same thing?

Comment: No. The set $\{0\}$ contains exactly one element: $0$. The empty set (denoted $\varnothing$) does not contain any elements. That makes them different.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are looking at the intersection over all non-negative integers. Then the answer should be the empty set. This can be trivially seen since one of the sets you are intersecting is the empty set, namely $(0,0)$. This by a happy accident also turns out to be $0$ if you are using the von Neumann construction of ordinals. So your answer could either be $0$ (if you felt like being clever and possibly arguing your case) or $\emptyset$ which is more straightforward. What your answer can't be is $\{\emptyset\}$ since the empty set is not contained in the intersection.

Just for clarification $\{\}=\emptyset=0$ which is not equal to $\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\}\}=1$. The numbers $0$ and $1$ here follow from the von Neuman construction of ordinals which you can read more about on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) . This is not the only way of constructing the integers, but IMO it really is the best.